# Incorrect Message When Rejected From Gaming

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, stackexchange-2.0

I got the following message when [I tried to access the Gaming beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/login):

> This site is currently in private beta; it is only visible to users who committed to the Web Apps Area 51 proposal ( http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications ) at the moment. Please come back for the public beta on July 7th after 7 pm (UTC).

This is obviously the same message they were giving to people who tried to access Web Apps before now.

Comment: Also, isn't it after 7pm UTC?

Comment: @Michael Yup. It's 7:49 i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, good catch. I made this more helpful and gave a generic link that will work for all future site proposals.